# How can I indicate end of page using html and css

Tags: html, css

I  am creating a profile page and on that page there is a div which spans 100 percent of the page. After I set the height and margins and refresh page there is a colored div, the height that I want with no white space. When I try to do the same for my end of page and set overflow hidden, instead of the page ending there,I am able to scroll and see the page continuing. My goal is to have all my content in between the whitespace of top and bottom divs. This is not homework, it is my personal project.

Thank You in advance for your help and time.

Attached is my html code:

```css
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.blue{
  width: 100%;
  height:70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(208, 210, 255);
  color: rgb(190,91,93);
  position:absolute;
}

.vanilla{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(250,0,0);
  color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  text-decoration:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  top:600px;
}
```

```html
        

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">

    </div>

    <div class="vanilla">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following is what I originally attempted:

```css
#body2{
  background-color: rgb(255,253,208);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


#me{
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 435px;

}

.section1{
    width: 100%;
    height:70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(208, 210, 255);
    color: rgb(190,91,93);
    position:absolute;
}
:hover{
  color: white;
}

#about{
    position: relative;
    left: 535px;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 5px;
}
#age{
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 5px;
}

#education{
    position: relative;
    top: 440px;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#languages{
    position: relative;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 40px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
#languages ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
#comp_lang{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 380px;
    left: 815px;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
#comp_lang ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
#comp_lang2{
    position: relative;
    top: -245px;
    left: 870px;
    border: solid 3px rgb(190,91,93);
    display: table;
    background-color: rgb(208,210,255);
    color: rgb(75,0,130);
    padding: 5px;
}
#comp_lang2 ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.remarks{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 165px;
    height: 200 px;
}
#endgame{
  width: 100%;
  height:70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(208, 210, 255);
  color: rgb(190,91,93);
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
        

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>About Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css">
</head>
<body id="body2">
    <div id="me">
    <img src="profile2.jpg"alt="Hello" height=500px;>
    </div>

      <div class="section1">

        <h1 id="about"><b>Who is Intisar?</b></h1>

      </div>

      <div id="age">
          <h2> Age : </h2>
          <h3> I am 23 years old!</h3>
      </div>


      <div id="education">
          <h2> Education : </h2>
          <h3>
            I am a high-school graduate.<br>
            I am in my third year<br>
            at something College.<br>
            I am studying<br>
            Software Development and Design.<br>
            Interest in Web Development and Design<br>
          </h3>
      </div>

      <div id="languages">
          <h2> Trilingual in :</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>English</li>
            <li>Bengali</li>
            <li>Spanish</li>
          </ul>
      </div>


      <div id="comp_lang">
          <h2> Computer Lanuguages I am competent in  : <br> </h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Python</li>
            <li>C++</li>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>Javascript</li>
            <li>SQL</li>
            <li>PHP</li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="comp_lang2">
          <h2> Lanuguages and software in Progress : </h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Wordpress</li>
            <li>Ruby</li>
          </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="endgame">
        <h3>Something</h3>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A snippet could be useful to help you.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by css grid, the current approach is not very good.

I wrote a little bit of code for you. If you don't understand it, let me know.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-rows.asp

It might be tricky for you if you are not fimiliar with grid, so let me know if you need help.

[Preview here](https://jsfiddle.net/tpn2qsr9/51/)

```
<div class="parent">
  <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
  <main>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605032659978-a5bd04094a16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603943817715-f50e0a2c413a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605910470315-abac78c52d73?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max">
  </main>
  <footer><h1>Footer Content</h1></footer>
</div>


<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
main{
  overflow:auto;
}

// css below this is just for styling

footer, header, main{
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
footer{
  background-color:red;
}
header{
  background-color:yellow
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code to keep everything within the view-port and work on whitespace area .

```css
    *{
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      box-sizing:border-box;
     }

    body{
      height:100vh;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      justify-content:space-between;
    }

    .blue{
      width: 100%;
      height:70px;
      text-decoration: none;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: rgb(208, 210, 255);
      color: rgb(190,91,93);
    }

    .vanilla{
      background-color: rgb(250,0,0);
      color:black;
      width:100%;
      height:100px;
      text-decoration:none;
      overflow:hidden;
      top:600px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">

    </div>

    <div class="vanilla">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @IntisarRatul : Do let me know whether this helps, Click on Run code snippet button in at the bottom of my answer and see whether your requirement is  fulfilled :) Enjoy Coding